# M2 - Can i set the how filters on admin page(Catalog/Order) show as default?

Tags: magento-2.1

Outside of Magento1, the filters ware hidden until an admin clicks filter icon on Magento2. But it is so irritating to me whenever i want to search product name and sku.

Can i make them fixed as opened like this??

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can set active to filter tab using jquery

Comment: Could you let me know how to do it specifically?